# find object from mongodb

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

In the data bellow, I would like to find the reminder where `_id=abc1` and the month is `1`. The date stored in db is text.

I try to use this command but it have error:
 db.check.find( {_id:"abc1"}, { reminder: { $regex: {date:2015-1/} }} ).pretty();

How can I do it?
The expected result is { date: "2005-1-5", event: "MeetingB" }, { date: "2005-1-4", event: "MeetingA" }

```
{

    _id: "abc1",
    reminder:[
        {
                date: "2005-1-5",
                event: "MeetingB"
        },
        {
                date: "2005-1-4",
                event: "MeetingA"
        },
        {
                date: "2005-2-4",
                event: "MeetingA"
        }
    ]
}

{

    _id: "abc2",
    reminder:[
        {
                date: "2005-1-5",
                event: "MeetingB"
        }
    ]

}
```

Comment: Unclear question, please provide more details (what did you try, what did you get, what was the expected result, ...)

Comment: I'd put money on it that this is about the "array" containing both month "1" and "2". But the first comment here is the most truthful. "Doesn't work" is not an explanation without the code you tried and  an expected result.

Comment: @John313 - You can edit your post to update what you have tried. Posting in the comments, makes it tougher and the question still wouldn't grasp attention..

Comment: Is your date property just text or is it an ISODate ?

Comment: My date is just text

Comment: By having a real date format you could query on it by using .getMonth()

Comment: Making `_id` not unique seems very suspect to me.

Answer (score 0):

It think you have 2 solutions :

1. The first one is to [`aggregate`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) your search in another to get
   only the month.
2. Query on the date

With this example (I haven't tested but it should looks like this):

```
db.check.find( { 
  $and: [ 
    { "_id": { $in: ["abc1"] } }, 
    { "reminder.date": { $in: [/2005-1*/] }  } 
  ] 
} );
```

You cannot use [`regex`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#op._S_regex) in a `in` and you have to use [JavaScript regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

However it will return the full object and not a partial object as apparently you want to.

Comment: It shows "SyntaxError: Unexpected token :" How can I fix it..?

Comment: The result will return the full object
{

    _id: "abc1",
    reminder:[
        {
                date: "2005-1-5",
                event: "MeetingB"
        },
        {
                date: "2005-1-4",
                event: "MeetingA"
        },
        {
                date: "2005-2-4",
                event: "MeetingA"
        }
    ]
}
If I want to only get the result
{ date: "2005-1-5", event: "MeetingB" }, { date: "2005-1-4", event: "MeetingA" } 
How can I do it..?

Comment: Yes as I said you cannot return a partial object with this example, you might want to have a look to map-reduce http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/ in that case